# From Keyword not found where expected - Oracle CRXI command

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I'm trying to create a union as a command in CR XI on an Oracle Database. But when i try to save the command is states that the 'FROM keyword not found where expected'.

Code seems ok? Any ideas?

```
SELECT *, "H3"  as "Type" FROM TABLEH3
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, "H4" as "Type" FROM TABLEH4
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT *,  "H5" AS "Type" FROM TABLEH5
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT *, "'H6" AS "Type" FROM TABLEH6
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1';
```

Cheers

Brendan

Comment: Can you share the structure of all your tables?

Answer (score 1):

i don't have your table structures, but this might work for you, you need to alias the table referenced by *

```
SELECT t1.*, 'H3'  as "Type" FROM TABLEH3 t1
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT t4.*, 'H4' as "Type" FROM TABLEH4 t4
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT t5.*, 'H5' AS "Type" FROM TABLEH5 t5
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT t6.*, 'H6' AS "Type" FROM TABLEH6 t6
WHERE CURRENT_FLAG = '1';
```